# JSF command button updating even there are validation errors

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm new to JSF, my question may be silly for you.. It is very much valuable for me..

```
<h:form id="form1">
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetails="true" />
    <p:dataTable id='form1ID'>....</dataTable>
        <p:inputText value="#{bean.name}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please Enter Name!" label="Name ">
        </p:inputText>
</h:form>

<h:form id="form2">
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetails="true" />
    <p:dataTable id='form2ID'>....</dataTable>
        <p:inputText value="#{bean.name}" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Please Enter Name!" label="Name ">
        </p:inputText>
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":form1:form1ID"
            actionListener="#{mgmtBean.doCreateType}" />
</h:form>
```

I have two forms. when I click on form2 command button with empty fields, it will show error messages perfectly since i have added `<p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/>`.

The bad thing or surprising thing here for me is, it is showing error messages on top of form1 also may be because of `<p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/>` added in form1 and i'm trying to update form1 on command button click in form2.
I don't want to show error messages on form1 when form2 is throwing validation error messages. How can i fix this ? I googled it out.. but couldn't find the solution.

Evironment i'm using is jsf-api-2.1.5 and primefaces 4.0 version and view technology is facelets(XHTML)
 Hope it is clear..

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by using the following code

```
<p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetails="true" visibility="info"/>
```

so it is just displaying info messages and other pop up error messages will not be showun.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable rendering of messages on the form1:

```
   <p:messages autoUpdate="true" showDetails="true" rendered="#{bean.renderedmessage}"/>
```

And in the bean, add the renderedmessage variable:

```
   public Boolean getRenderedmessage() {
   return renderedmessage;
   }

   /**
   * @param renderedmessage the renderedmessage to set
   */
   public void setRenderedmessage(Boolean renderedmessage) {
   this.renderedmessage = renderedmessage;
   }
```

And, for the doCreateType() method, add:

```
  public void doCreateType(){
  ..............
  setRenderedmessage(false);
  .............
  }
```

After the form1 is updated, you can choose some event or method, where you can setRenderedmessage(true);

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently experiencing should indicate to you that you usually don't need two `<p:messages/>`s in the same JSF view; one is enough.

Regardless of the fact that you have two `<h:form/>`s on your page, there's still only one `FacesContext` associated with that view (The `FacesContext` object is a JSF construct that encapsulates all the information/data/components etc that's associated with a given JSF page request).

**By default the `<p:messages/>` will display every `FacesMessage` that is queued within it's associated instance of `FacesContext`**, regardless of the source of the message (well, almost: if you set `globalOnly="true"` on the `<p:messages/>`, you can change that behaviour).

---

That being said, you basically have two options:

1. Get rid of the extra `<p:messages/>` and rely on (and appropriately position) only one to display all errors/warnings for that view
2. Specify the `for` attribute, set to the desired component. Doing so, you'll guarantee that only one input component can trigger the display of its associated message component. For example

   ```
   <h:form id="form1">
      <p:messages for="inputName" autoUpdate="true" showDetails="true" />
      <p:dataTable id='form1ID'>....</dataTable>
         <p:inputText id="inputName" value="#{bean.name}" required="true"
             requiredMessage="Please Enter Name!" label="Name ">
         </p:inputText>
   </h:form>
   ```

   Note that I've set an `id` attribute on the `<p:inputText/>` component; this is necessary so you can use it in the `for` attribute for the `messages` component.

Further reading:

- [What is FacesContext used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865353/what-is-faces-context-used-for)